# Azure Network Interface, change "Primary" IP configuration

Tags: azure-networking

I have an Azure VM with multiple static IP addresses. I had to delete and recreate the VM a couple times due to lost connectivity, and ended up with this IP Configuration:

[image]

It automatically assigned 10.0.0.12 as "Primary" but I would like to make the 10.0.0.4 "Primary" and remove the 10.0.0.12 to get back to the original configuration I had.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the name "10.0.0.4" Secondary type IP first, if not, you will have IP conflict when you add the same IP to another IP configuration. Then run the following PowerShell script to set the private IP address of the primary IP configuration ipconfig1 to 10.0.0.4.

```
$vnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name myvnet -ResourceGroupName myrg
$subnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name mysubnet -VirtualNetwork $vnet
$publicIP = Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -name publicIpName -ResourceGroupName myrg
$publicIp.PublicIpAllocationMethod = "Static"
$nic = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name nic1 -ResourceGroupName myrg  
$nic | Set-AzureRmNetworkInterfaceIpConfig -Name ipconfig1 -PrivateIpAddress 10.0.0.4 -Subnet $subnet -Primary -PublicIpAddress $publicIP
$nic | Set-AzureRmNetworkInterface
```

Then you can add a new IP configuration as the Private IP address 10.0.0.12 back.

Ref: [Set-AzureRmNetworkInterfaceIpConfig](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.network/set-azurermnetworkinterfaceipconfig?view=azurermps-6.8.1)

Answer (score 0):

You can also check this documents :

[Assign multiple IP addresses to virtual machines using    PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-powershell)

[Assign multiple IP addresses to virtual machines using the Azure    portal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-portal)

[Assign multiple IP addresses to virtual machines using the Azure    CLI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-cli)